# How do I show multiple times a dialog defined with Glade?

Tags: python, dialog, gtk3, pygtk, pygobject

I would like to show a `Gtk.Dialog` defined in a Glade file multiple times.

Currently I am able to do it using a custom button to call the `hide()` method of the Dialog but, if the user uses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close the dialog, it re-opens empty:

[image]

And in console I see multiple errors:

```
(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.637: gtk_container_foreach: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.651: _gtk_container_get_border_width_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.651: gtk_container_set_border_width: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.651: _gtk_container_set_border_width_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.651: _gtk_box_get_spacing_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_BOX (box)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.651: gtk_box_set_spacing: assertion 'GTK_IS_BOX (box)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.651: _gtk_box_set_spacing_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_BOX (box)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.651: gtk_button_box_get_layout: assertion 'GTK_IS_BUTTON_BOX (widget)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.651: gtk_box_set_spacing: assertion 'GTK_IS_BOX (box)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.651: _gtk_container_get_border_width_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.651: gtk_container_set_border_width: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.651: _gtk_container_set_border_width_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.697: _gtk_container_get_border_width_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.697: gtk_container_set_border_width: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.697: _gtk_container_set_border_width_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.697: _gtk_box_get_spacing_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_BOX (box)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.697: gtk_box_set_spacing: assertion 'GTK_IS_BOX (box)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.697: _gtk_box_set_spacing_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_BOX (box)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.697: gtk_button_box_get_layout: assertion 'GTK_IS_BUTTON_BOX (widget)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.697: gtk_box_set_spacing: assertion 'GTK_IS_BOX (box)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.697: _gtk_container_get_border_width_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.697: gtk_container_set_border_width: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:29.697: _gtk_container_set_border_width_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:31.141: _gtk_container_get_border_width_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:31.141: gtk_container_set_border_width: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:31.141: _gtk_container_set_border_width_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:31.141: _gtk_box_get_spacing_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_BOX (box)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:31.141: gtk_box_set_spacing: assertion 'GTK_IS_BOX (box)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:31.141: _gtk_box_set_spacing_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_BOX (box)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:31.141: gtk_button_box_get_layout: assertion 'GTK_IS_BUTTON_BOX (widget)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:31.141: gtk_box_set_spacing: assertion 'GTK_IS_BOX (box)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:31.141: _gtk_container_get_border_width_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:31.141: gtk_container_set_border_width: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed

(main.py:29152): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:28:31.141: _gtk_container_set_border_width_set: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed
```

I am getting the instance of the Dialog with a normal `get_object()`:

```
 self.__settings_dialog : Gtk.Dialog = self.__builder.get_object("settings_dialog")
```

and than just calling `show()` and `hide()`. But after closing it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> I am not able to show it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [a Reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/GTK/comments/9mf0sg/how_to_show_multiple_times_a_dialog_defined_with/e7e5tuk/), I find out that you have to connect to the dialog's `delete-event` and make sure to return `True` to avoid the dialog being destroyed.

First create the signal handler in Glade, then in your Python code:

```
def on_dialog_delete_event(self, dialog, event):
    dialog.hide()
    return True
```

Comment: Thats exactly what [`GtkWidget::hide_on_delete`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.hide_on_delete) does. Simply connect your window's `delete-event` to it, no need to create your own callback.

Comment: I am connecting my callback from Glade, is it possible to connect directly `hide_on_delete ` from Glade?